# How to add filters to a superset dashboard that will add a where condition to the inner query?

Tags: apache-superset

Add filters for column that isn't selected in SQLlab in superset.

I have a table like

| ID | score | Date | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 1 | 2023-06-05 | 1 |
| 2011 | 2 | 2023-06-05 | 2 |
| 2012 | 2 | 2023-06-04 | 1 |
| 2013 | 0 | 2023-06-04 | 1 |

Now I need to generate a table with a formula like
`value = (count(*)) / (count(distinct id) with score > 0)`

so I wrote an SQL query that uses a similar logic in SQL Lab which works fine

```
SELECT FINAL_COUNT/DISTINCT_COUNT, DATE FROM
    ( 
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS FINAL_COUNT FROM TABLE
     GROUP BY Date
    ) A
   INNER JOIN 
    (
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS DISTINCT_COUNT, DATE FROM TABLE
     WHERE SCORE > 0
     GROUP BY Date
    ) B
   ON A.DATE=B.DATE
```

I am displaying the final result in a line chart.

Once I add it to dashboards I wanted a filter `version` that would apply a `where` condition to the two inner queries like

```
SELECT FINAL_COUNT/DISTINCT_COUNT, DATE FROM
    ( 
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS FINAL_COUNT FROM TABLE
     WHERE VERSION = 1
     GROUP BY Date
    ) A
   INNER JOIN 
    (
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS DISTINCT_COUNT, DATE FROM TABLE
     WHERE VERSION = 1
     WHERE SCORE > 0
     GROUP BY Date
    ) B
   ON A.DATE=B.DATE
```

How should I do this? I understand that one way is I can include a jinja template in SQLlab query to achive this but I'm not sure on how to do it as there's very little documentation on this.

Comment: I keep running into this, exactly what I need as well :/